# Is $R(T)$ a closed subspace of $\ell^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be the diagonal operator on the Hilbert space $\ell^2$ such that
$$T=\text{diag}(0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots).$$
Clearly the range of $T$ denoted $R(T)$ is not $\ell^2$ since $e_1=(1,0,0...)\notin R(T)$.

> Is $R(T)$ a closed subspace of $\ell^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not closed. The sequences $(0,\frac  1 {1^{3/2}},\frac  1 {2^{3/2}},..., \frac  1 {N^{3/2}},0,0,...)$, $N=1,2,...$, are all in the range of $T$ but their limit $(0,\frac  1 {1^{3/2}},\frac  1 {3^{3/2}},,...)$ is not in the range of $T$: If you write this as $T(a_n)$ you would get $\sum a_n^{2}=\infty$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But please how you calculate the timit of the given sequence?

Comment: @Schüler $\|(0,\frac  1 {1^{3/2}},\frac  1 {2^{3/2}},..., \frac  1 {N^{3/2}},0,0,...)-(0,\frac  1 {1^{3/2}},\frac  1 {2^{3/2}},...)\|^{2}=\sum_{n>N} \frac 1 {n^{3}} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$ so the sequence $(0,\frac  1 {1^{3/2}},\frac  1 {2^{3/2}},..., \frac  1 {N^{3/2}},0,0,...)$ converges to $(0,\frac  1 {1^{3/2}},\frac  1 {2^{3/2}},...)$ in $\ell^{2}$ norm.